# PHP if not empty string and either string = "this" or "that" how to do that?

Tags: php, if-statement, var, equals-operator

```
function test(){
$embedmode = 'normal';
if ( ( $embedmode != '' ) && ( $embedmode != 'normal' || $embedmode != 'popup' || $embedmode != 'popup' ) )
    return "<p>ARVE Error: mode is not set to 'normal', 'popup' or 'special' maybe typo</p>";
elseif ( $embedmode == '')
    $mode = 'default';
else
    $mode = $embedmode;

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($mode);
echo "</pre>";
}
echo test();
```

this is my attempt and I am getting a headache now it puts out the return message and I don't know why

Comment: Depends on operator precedence in whatever language that is.

Comment: I'm not an expert in PHP but I would suggest that one tests directly for inequality, the other negates the operand befoe comparing for equality. What is the result of the negation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bad logic is here:

```
( $embedmode != 'normal' || $embedmode != 'popup' || $embedmode != 'popup' )
```

if `$embedmode` equals `'normal'`, then `$embedmode != 'popup'`, so this whole bit is TRUE. I believe you want to replace || with &&.

For code that's easier to reason about, I'd probably use `in_array` or `switch`, like this:

```
switch ($embedmode) {
  case 'normal':
  case 'popup':
  case 'special':
    // valid, proceed
    break;
  case '':
    $embedmode = 'default';
    break;
  default:
    trigger_error ("Embed mode '$embedmode' not valid.");
    break;
}
```

Comment: lol i just figured it out myself and after this i watched your post. still strange that when i used this in another case with == it worked `$iframe = false;
if ($provider == "dailymotion" ||
 $provider == "dailymotionlist" ||
 $provider == "youtube" ||
 $provider == "youtubelist" ||
 $provider == "vimeo" ||
 $provider == "collegehumor" ||
 $provider == "funnyordie" ||
 $provider == "bliptv")
 $iframe = true;`

Comment: @peaceinfo, not strange, if you think about it. Glad you figured it out, though. Two other tips: I like to use brackets even for single-line statements, so things don't break if I need to add a line. And using named constants for the valid values might be helpful to avoid typos and make changes easier. (i.e. don't use [Magic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants).)

Answer (score 5):

`!($var == 'something')` would be the same as `($var != 'something')`.

Doing `(!$var == 'something')` would perform the boolean operation on $var before doing the comparison. !$var would return false unless $var is empty, so it would essentially be saying (false == 'something'), which would be false.

Answer (score 2):

1) `$var != 'something'` says "$var IS NOT 'something'".

2) `!$var == 'something'` says "THE NEGATION OF $var IS 'something'".

The expressions mean different things. Test it with saying $var is 'foobar', your two sentences are:

1) 'foobar' IS NOT 'something', and

2) THE NEGATION OF 'foobar' is 'something'

As you can see, 1) will return true, yet 2) will return false, because the negation of whatever 'foobar' is, it is still not equal to 'something'.

Comment: ok thanks looks like test2 is not doing what i really want liek i guessed. so how to get test1 working?